# Regex that matches a word but only if another word doesn't appear?

Tags: python, regex

I'm usually pretty good with Regex but I'm struggling with this one.  I need a regular expression that matches the term `cbd` but not if the phrase `central business district` appears *anywhere* else in the search string.  Or if that is too difficult, at least matches `cbd` if the phrase `central business district` doesn't appear *anywhere before* the term `cbd`.  Only the `cbd` part should be returned as the result, so I'm using lookaheads/lookbehinds, but I have not been able to meet the requirements...

Input examples:
GOOD
`Any products containing CBD are to be regulated.`
BAD    `Properties located within the Central Business District (CBD) are to be regulated`

I have tried:

- `(?!central business district)cbd`
- `(.*(?!central business district).*)cbd`

This is in Python 3.6+ using the `re` module.

I know it would be easy to accomplish with a couple lines of code, but we have a list of regex strings in a database that we are using to search a corpus for documents that contain any one of the regex strings from the DB.  It is best to avoid hard-coding any keywords into the scripts because then it would not be clear to our other developers where these matches are coming from because they can't see it in the database.

Comment: can you post some input examples? any code that your trying?

Comment: Could you provide a sample string of what you are looking for? Could you not search the string for `central business district` and then search for `cbd` if it is not present in the string afterward? Then you don't need a fancy regex at all

Comment: .* will match anything including "central business district"

Comment: Why a Regex when a single line of code can do it? `print("cdb" in text and not "central business district" in text)`. People are too obsessed by Regex.

Comment: You are close. Try `^(?!.*central business district).*cbd` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UgB0SB/1/) That assumes a single line string.

Comment: Can you use [PyPi Regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/)? To [skip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex): [`^.*?central business district.*(*SKIP)(*F)|cbd`](https://regex101.com/r/rQudrv/1)

Comment: Hope my answer was of help to you,  wasn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PyPi regex with

```py
import regex
strings = [' I need a regular expression that matches the term cbd but not if the phrase central business district appears anywhere else in the search string.', 'I need cbd here.']
for s in strings:
  x = regex.search(r'(?<!central business district.*)cbd(?!.*central business district)', s, regex.S)
  if x:
    print(s, x.group(), sep=" => ")
```

Results: `I need cbd here. => cbd`. See [Python code](https://tio.run/##dY@xbsMwEEN3fwWTxXYQaOlW1M3cuWPRQbEvlgBHEk5n1Pl69@R4zSiRx0emh7gY3tbV31NkAdNIS5WFfRgzOvzU@EIgGmCLNk@WQUtiytnHAHFWcLfSO8r6IAjxHf11wHUWhCjwt@0/ObaZ0FMQtpOq2QfNwOALqxfYlMhyhg2PP0dMoEn9PmzXWaXe4VnL1GfUe6lCKm5T/1a3yMjlYm//XgGLTtgmmWdEw3Vz@Ti8rGFOrUY2l4M5vfS0ys/nPfa7VYpuXAoNSEqWRtXFjBzn1LTqpdQd0X3i2K7rPw).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    central business         'central business district'
    district
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  cbd                      'cbd'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    central business         'central business district'
    district
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  I actually tried this pattern with the standard `re` module and it produces an error:
```python
error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
```
So anybody reading this in the future, install the `regex` module with pip and this solution will work:
```bash
pip install regex
```

Comment: @mevers303 `pip install regex` should be enough.

Comment: Right... I've been writing so many bash scripts I preceded it with `bash` out of muscle memory ~_~